# mpirun qiskit code doesn't return parallel processing

Tags: qiskit

I am trying to create MPI cluster and run qiskit code on two nodes each with a single GPU installed. Till now I have installed MPI4PY and qiskit-aer-gpu on each node and ran a test script which is do executing on both master and worker nodes.

Code I am executing is a test script

```
from qiskit import *
from qiskit.circuit.library import *
from qiskit.providers.aer import *
sim = AerSimulator(method='statevector’, device=‘GPU’, blocking_qubits=20)
shots = 100
depth=10
qubits = 35
circuit = transpile(QuantumVolume(qubits, depth, seed=0), backend=sim, optimization_level=0)
circuit.measure_all()
result = execute(circuit,sim,shots=shots,seed_simulator=12345).result()
if result.to_dict()['metadata']['mpi_rank'] == 0:
    print(result.to_dict()['metadata'])
```

I am using following command

```
mpirun -np 2 -machinefile machinefile.txt python3 demo.py
```

And the output showing for each processes

```
{mpi_rank : 0, 'num_mpi_processes':1, 'max_gpu_memory_mb':5933, 'max:memory_mb':15903, 'parallel_experiments':1, 'num_processes_per_experiments':1, 'opm_enabled': True}
{mpi_rank : 0, 'num_mpi_processes':1, 'max_gpu_memory_mb':5933, 'max:memory_mb':15903, 'parallel_experiments':1, 'num_processes_per_experiments':1, 'opm_enabled': True}
```

which shows that each process is running a separate/independent script and has `mpi_rank = 0 and nnum_mpi_processes = 1`. However I want to share resources of both nodes to execute program for which I have used `blocking_enable='True'` and set `blocking_qubits=n`

I am also concerned about installing qiskit-aer-gpu, should I build it from source in order to run it with openmpi?

Thanks